# Titanium studio function executes in reverse (Android)

Tags: android, alert, titanium-mobile, reverse

I'm new to Titanium Studio and I'm trying to develop an application for android. When I executed the following function(ie, when I click on the window):

```
win1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('On click');
    alert('End of the function');
});
```

the alert number two "End of the function" is shown first and the the alert number one, "On click" is shown.

Do you have any solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Titanium, the `alert()` call is asynchronous (unlike in web browsers). [Heres the doc on it:](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Global-method-alert)

> Note that unlike a web browser-based version of alert, the method is asynchronous. However, only one alert dialog will be visible and
>   modal at a time.
>
> Be aware that this method may be removed in the future.

You have two alerts triggered from inside one function, the second alert did not open first, they are opening in sequence, so when you open the first `alert('On Click')` it gets covered up (or really replaced since only one alert is shown at a time) almost immediately by opening the second alert box.

You should never have multiple alert calls in one function because of this.

Thinking about best practices in Javascript and Titanium : you should **never** use `alert()` to debug modern javascript especially when you have much more robust tools at your disposal. Even in the web browser (use Web Developer Tools or Firebug).  Also, this functionality may be removed from Titanium in the future (and I hope they do) as noted.

Instead use the built in debugger in the Debug perspective. It functions just like any other visual debugger out there. But here is a quick link if your new to this in general : [Debugging with Titanium](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/guide/About_the_Debug_perspective)

The other option is to use the `printf()` / `console.log` equivalent of Titanium which is:

```
Titanium.API.info('On click');
```

But why not step through the code and save yourself some trouble.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. That makes sense. But when I tried the same with IOS, it worked as expected. Does titanium works differently in Windows and MacOS.And thanks for your tips for debugging.

Comment: Yes this happens because the implementations are different for each platform, note that the doc said "only one alert() is modal and visible at a time" since its a native component these will function differently on different platforms (Android vs iOS) so my answer is still correct. TitaniumStudio works the same for Window and MacOS, Titanium the platform is implemented differently for each device.

Comment: Thank you Josiah. That's quite helpful.